# Cannot open file /gc.log due to Permission denied

Tags: cassandra

I just installed cassandra manually.
Encountered the following issue while starting.
Cannot open file /gc.log due to Permission denied.

How do I go about fixing this issues ?

Thanks
Siva

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly as the error message states -- Cassandra doesn't have permission to access the log file.

The most likely cause of this is that you accidentally started Cassandra as `root` so all files including the logs are now owned by `root`.

You will need to reset the ownership on the log files so they are owned by `cassandra` (or whatever OS account you are using). Note that it may also be necessary to reset the permissions on the directories. Cheers!